# Make Minecraft commands take priority over plugin commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm running EssentialsX on my Minecraft server and I don't like the EssentialsX versions of the Minecraft commands they add. To allow me to use the Minecraft ones like I would traditionally, I disabled many of these commands in the EssentialsX config file. When I do, then I try to use the `/give` command for example, rather than just using the Minecraft give command, it gives me an error message saying that the command is disabled until I use it like this `/minecrarft:give` Is there a way for me to make Minecraft commands take priority over ones added by plugins? having to add the "minecraft:" keyword before using give every time is a little annoying.